# Executing a binary downloaded from HTTP server with PowerShell fails with "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable"

Tags: powershell, installation, winscp

I am new to PowerShell and don't have much of a programming background, just trying  to use below power shell script to install few softwares. The script throws error while executing for WinSCP software.

Error message

```
Program 'WinSCP-5.13.1-Setup.exe' failed to run: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadableAt line:1 char:1
+ D:\softwares\WinSCP-5.13.1-Setup.exe /
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ D:\softwares\WinSCP-5.13.1-Setup.exe /SP
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Script:

```
$source = 'D:\softwares' 

If (!(Test-Path -Path $source -PathType Container)) {New-Item -Path $source -ItemType Directory | Out-Null} 

$packages = @( 
@{title='7zip Extractor';url='http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7z920-x64.msi';Arguments=' /qn';Destination=$source}, 
@{title='Notepad++ 7.5.6';url='https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.5.6/npp.7.5.6.Installer.exe';Arguments=' /Q /S';Destination=$source} 
@{title='WinScp 5.13.1';url='https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-5.13.1-Setup.exe';Arguments=' /';Destination=$source} 
) 

foreach ($package in $packages) { 
    $packageName = $package.title 
    $fileName = Split-Path $package.url -Leaf 
    $destinationPath = Join-Path $package.Destination $fileName

    If (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Leaf)) { 

        Write-Host "Downloading $packageName" 
        $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
        $webClient.DownloadFile($package.url,$destinationPath) 
        #Start-Sleep -s 10
    }

    #Once we've downloaded all our files lets install them. 
    foreach ($package in $packages) { 
        $packageName = $package.title 
        $fileName = Split-Path $package.url -Leaf 
        $destinationPath = Join-Path $package.Destination $fileName 
        $Arguments = $package.Arguments 
        Write-Output "Installing $packageName" 

        Invoke-Expression -Command "$destinationPath $Arguments" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`https://winscp.net/download/WinSCP-5.13.1-Setup.exe` is not a download URL. It's a download page. Your code downloads an HTML document, not an executable binary.

You actually cannot download a binary automatically from WinSCP site. It's designed to prevent an abuse of its bandwidth, for uses like yours.

The URL above gets you an executable file only because the HTML, that it returns, includes a JavaScript code that redirects your browser to one-time download URL. Of course, you can implement the same (get the HTML and find/generate the download URL using the data it returns). But it's an abuse.